# asymptote cmyk output

Tags: asymptote

I need asymptote to output cmyk figures with only the cyan and black channels used. I've tried the -cmyk option but grayscale colors seem to be coded in the c m and y channels even though I use a `pen` color like `cmyk{0,0,0,.9}`. Here is an example:

```
import three;
size(8cm,0);

currentprojection=perspective(
              camera=(14.2,8.0,7.6),
              zoom=2
);

path3 plan_Oxy= plane((1,0,0), (0,1,0), O);
path3 plan_Oxz = plane((1,0,0), (0,0,1), O);;
path3 plagqsdfn_Oyz = plane((0,1,0), (0,0,1), O);;

pen style_plan = cmyk(0,0,0,0.9);
pen DarkDuotone = cmyk(1,0,0,.4);

draw(surface(plan_Oxy),style_plan,style_plan);
draw(surface(plan_Oxz),style_plan,style_plan);
draw(surface(plan_Oyz),style_plan,style_plan);


path3 axe_Ox = O -- 1*X;
path3 axe_Oy = O -- 1*Y;
path3 axe_Oz = O -- 1*Z;

draw(axe_Ox, DarkDuotone);
draw(axe_Oy, DarkDuotone);
draw(axe_Oz, DarkDuotone);
```

I compiled with

`asy -f pdf -noV -noprc -cmyk EMC-cmyk-pb.asy -o test.pdf`
and
`asy -noprc -cmyk EMC-cmyk-pb.asy -o test.eps`

and checked the files produced with `identify`.

test.pdf is indeed in CMYK but there is some magenta and yellow components
test.eps is in sRGB.

What should I do to get the grays use only the k channel ?